# Unable to log in to django admin

Tags: python, django

I know this question has been asked before, but either I don't understand how to apply the solutions provided or they don't work. I think my case may be much simpler.

I am a beginner with Django and I'm following first the djangogirls tutorial. I installed Django in a virtual environment that I created with `conda`. The first time I tried it, I was perfectly able to create a superuser and log in to the account successfully. However, that time I created the project in `C:\Users\User\` and it was not very organized since there were a whole lot of files and folders there along with the project.

Now, I created a second virtual environment and a new project, which is in F:, another partition of the same drive. I did everything I had done the first time, but when I tried to log in to the admin page, I get a message saying the credentials are incorrect. Actually, I created other two superusers (successfully), but always get the same message.

I also created a third virtual environment and project (in the same partition where the OS is not), this time with pip, to follow exactly the same process in the djangogirls tutorial. However, the exact same thing happened. I thought maybe, for the project with the virtual environment created with `conda`, the project had to be in the same partition as the OS, which is why I created a third project using the same virtual environment but in the C drive. Always the same error.

I tried creating a new superuser for the very first app I was creating (the one that wasn't organized), and it was created successfully and I was able to log in successfully too.

From all the answers I have read, there might be something wrong with the database, but I don't understand how to apply those solutions.

I'm using Windows 10. Python 3.7.6 and Django 3.0.3.

**EDIT 1**

The exact steps I'm following (and their order) are the following:

1. Create project with

`django-admin.exe startproject myproject .`

in a dedicated directory in the drive F (partition. Windows is in C).

2. In the settings.py file, change the time zone, add the path for static files with `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')`, change `ALLOWED_HOSTS` value with `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', '.pythonanywhere.com']`, as the tutorial specifies.
3. I'm using the default sqlite3, and setting it up with

`python manage.py migrate`

After this I run the server and everything looks great so far.

4. Create the application with

`python manage.py startapp blog`

as the tutorial specifies.

5. Add the app to the `INSTALLED_APPS` variable

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
]
```

6. Create a new model for a blog post.
7. Add the new model to the database, like so:

```
python manage.py makemigrations blog
python manage.py migrate blog
```

**EDIT 2** (forgot to add this step)

8. Register the model in the admin.py file with

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Post

admin.site.register(Post)
```

9. Create a super user with `python manage.py createsuperuser`, which is successful.

Then, after doing this, I can't log in, which originally worked.

Comment: Users don't really have anything to do with your virtual environment. They're saved in your database. Did you create a new database each time you moved the project? Have you created a super user in the _current_ database? Unfortunately, we can't help much without more detail, ideally as a [mcve]. Can you [edit] your question and add the exact commands you're running?

Comment: what database are you using? sqlite3 or mysql or postgres? If sqlite3 can you check db file path is correct?

Comment: Try replacing SECRET_KEY in your settings file with that from the first project.

Comment: @Chris Edited the question. Actually, I created a new project every time, I didn't move it. I assume the `python manage.py migrate` in the database set up creates the database, as after this the db.sqlite3 file is created in the directory. I did this every time, so I think I created the superuser for the current database—made sure I was in the right directory.

Comment: @SatishReddy I'm using sqlite3 as in the tutorial. I'm not completely sure how to check the db file path. It is correctly created in the project directory and I can see it. Do you mean to check I'm addressing the correct db when I create the superuser? I'm making sure I'm in the right directory every time.

Comment: @akhilsp I'm about to try that, but why wouldn't the SECRET_KEY of the new project work?

Comment: @TheSprinter hmm. looks like your accessing right db file. weird issue! are you trying to login with username instead of email or something like that? that could be one possibility

Comment: @SatishReddy I edited a second time because I forgot to add the step in which I register the Post model in the admin.py file. I'm logging in with the username because it was the way it worked the first time and, well, it's what the log in page requests.

Comment: @akhilsp Changing the SECRET_KEY with the one from the first project didn't work. Created a new superuser after the change and still can't log in.

Comment: @TheSprinter: can you try copy sqlilte3 db file from your 1st project into your latest project and see if you are able to login with the creds same as in 1st project? that should work. take the db file backup before copying if its necessary

Comment: You need to migrate everything not only blog soo do python manage.py migrate

Comment: @SatishReddy That one worked. Copied the first db.sqlite3 file onto the latest project and I could log in running the server for it. Why is this happening? Are the new databases I'm creating wrong in some way? I can't see what's different because I'm doing the exact same thing.

Comment: @ngawang13 If I do that, I get `No migrations to apply` and the error persists.

Comment: @SatishReddy I think it's worth mentioning that after I could log in with the other database pasted in the latest project, I tried creating a new superuser to that database from that same latest project. It still didn't work. There is a problem creating the superusers, even though I always get the successful message.

Comment: @TheSprinter are you sure you activated same virtualenv for creating superadmin and running server? Its also possible that something wrong folder permissions. when you run and create superuser,. try run as adminstrator just to make sure

Comment: Try deleting the whole db and migrate again and check if the created superuser env is equal to the env that you run the server

Comment: @SatishReddy I did make sure the virtual environment was activated and correct and the server is running, each time. Ran as administrator, but still the same thing. This is really confusing. I mean, if I run the server from this project and with its venv activated, it's supposed to not have any conflict with anything else, right? I always get the `superuser created successfully message`. Is there a way to see the database and see what's in there in regards to the superusers?

Comment: @TheSprinter yes. you can do `python manage.py db` . now see and match the records with that is working vs not working

Comment: @ngawang13 That makes a lot of sense. Tried and still didn't work. Actually tried deleting the db file and running cmd as admin and then migrating again and creating the superuser. Still the same.

Comment: When you deleted the db and made the migrate did it remigrate everything cuz if it didnt the db was not deleted properly

Comment: @SatishReddy I got an error with `python manage.py db` saying it doesn't exist. However, I ran the help for `manage.py` and saw `dbshell` and `inspectdb`. `dbshell` didn't show anything interesting, and `inspectdb` actually showed a bunch of class definitions but nothing about the superusers created.

Comment: @ngawang13 I'm not sure how to tell if it remigrated everything. I got all the lines that you get when no previous migration is done, those that say "Applying contenttypes...," "Applying auth...," "Applying admin...," etc. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @TheSprinter did you try to compare superadmin records in the user table for both working case and not working case. can you copy paste the records? what do you mean by it didn't show anything interesting?

Comment: @SatishReddy How can I see the superadmin records and copy and paste them? By "it didn't show anything interesting' I meant in fact that I didn't see any record of users, it only showed `SQLite version 3.31.1` + date and time. Although now I entered `.help` and saw a bunch of options that could be helpful (like binary on|off, etc), but I really don't know which one (or if) could give the me list of created users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a lot of help from a user named Lowe Wilsson in a chat room dedicated to the djangogirls tutorial and that led to a solution to the problem.

The problem was—most likely—that one of the times I ran the server for the first project I created I didn't shut it down properly—closing the terminal window without stopping the server—and it kept running in the background, so every time I went to 127.0.0.1:8000 I was interacting with the first project's database. This explains why I could log in with the admin credentials for that first project even when I ran the server for another project.

Doing

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
User.objects.all()
```

I could see that all the users were created correctly in the database.

I ran the server at port 8001 instead and could log in without problems.